# laravel - jquery/ajax Data empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to make my comment submit form work without refresh, and append the data into a div to show the comment.
Currently the submit form works, it's inserted into the database so the data is passed to the controller, but it's not shown on console.log and the append.

JS

```
$("#newsCommentForm").submit(function(e){

  e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      method: 'POST',
      url: '/store',
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success:function(data){
          console.log( $( this ).serialize() );
        $('#test').append(data); 
      },
      error: function( e ) {
          console.log(e);
      }
  });
});
```

Controller

```
protected function storeNewsComment(Request $request)
{
     Comment::create([
         'user_id'  => Auth::user()->id,
         'blog_id'  => $request->input('blog_id'),
         'body'  => $request->input('body'),
     ]);
}
```

I made a test div in the view

```
<div id="test">

</div>
```

Comment: what output would you expect? is `storeNewsComment()` your action? if so, why is it protected? Also, it is not returning anything

Comment: Didn't realize the controller would need to return anything, I thought since data is defined in the Ajax and the console.log is called there, it's also stored there. What should I return then? I expect the output to be the userid/blogid/body

Comment: Thanks, you've put me on the right track and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to save the new comment to a variable and return it.

```
protected function storeNewsComment(Request $request)
{
    $comment = Comment::create([
        'user_id'  => Auth::user()->id,
        'blog_id'  => $request->input('blog_id'),
        'body'  => $request->input('body'),
    ]);

    return response($comment);
}
```

Comment: $return_array = compact('comment');
         return json_encode($return_array); seemed to work for me.

Comment: @MitchM Well, you can return the data the way it suits better your frontend.

Answer (score 0):

`this` has a different meaning in the `success` callback function, which refers to the [function's context](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this#Function_context). You need to save the reference to `this` before entering that function:

```
$("#newsCommentForm").submit(function(e){
  var self = this;
  // ... code truncated for brevity

  success: function() {
    console.log( $( self ).serialize() );
  }
 });
```